# Adding a PNG image to a WFS layer in an OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, wfs, angular

[image]

```
style: function () {
    var path = "./../../../assets/icon/"
    var featureImage = 'track.png';

    return new Style({
        image: new Icon({
            opacity: 1,
            src: path + featureImage,
            scale: 0.5
        }),

        //text: new Text({
        //text: '',
        //font: '15px sans-serif',

        fill: new Fill({
            color: '#000000'
        }),

        stroke: new Stroke({
            color: '#838383',
            width: 1
        }),

        //offsetX: 0,
        //offsetY: -7
    })
}
```

This is the code which I have added after my WFS layer, but image is not added to the layer.

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct?  What geometry types are you displaying?  An image style is only used for Point geometries.  If you wish to display an icon over a polygon the style will need a geometry function.

Comment: @Mike the geometry type is line string and path is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display an image on a LineString you will need a style array, one style with geometry function which returns a Point geometry (e.g. the midpoint of the line) where the image is to be placed, and another style to display the original LineString geometry.

```
[
  new Style({
    geometry: function(feature) {
      const geometry = feature.getGeometry();
      if (geometry.getType() === 'LineString') {
        return new Point(geometry.getCoordinateAt(0.5));
      } else {
        return geometry;
      }
    },
    image: new Icon({
        opacity: 1,
        src: path + featureImage,
        scale: 0.5
    }),
  }),
  new Style({
    //text: new Text({
    //text: '',
    //font: '15px sans-serif',

    fill: new Fill({
        color: '#000000'
    }),

    stroke: new Stroke({
        color: '#838383',
        width: 1
    }),
  }),
]
```

If you need multiple icons on the LineString the geometry function would need to return a MultiPoint geometry, for example for 6 points including the start and end of the line

```
geometry: function(feature) {
  const geometry = feature.getGeometry();
  if (geometry.getType() === 'LineString') {
    const showPoints = 6;
    const points = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < showPoints; i++) {
      points.push(geometry.getCoordinateAt(i / (showPoints - 1)));
    }
    return new MultiPoint(points);;
  } else {
    return geometry;
  }
},
```

Comment: -The image is not coming over the linestring

Comment: `()` were missing on `getType()`

Comment: Now the image is coming at the mid point of line string .Now I have to get the image on entire Line String. Can you help?

Comment: What do you mean by "entire line string"? It can be of any shape, horizontal, vertical ... A picture or two would help. Please edit your question and add some pics.

Comment: And if answer helped you solve your initial problem, it's customary on GIS SE site to mark it as accepted, to let other users with similar questions/problems know that problem was resolved.

Comment: The image is added at the mid point of the line string. Now I want to add that image on full Line String.

Comment: How often/how much apart? Please edit your question in describe this in more detail.